# Optimize nested for loop

Tags: optimization, treeview, nested-loops, gmap.net

I'm using GMAP.Net library for a mapping windows application.
I have about 17000 polygons on my Sql Server database. In form load event I select All polygons from database and fill a datatabale then draw polygons one by one from datatable. 
I also have a treeview which I add all 17000 polygon names to that treeview.
Now when I check select all checkbox on treeview I call a function in Treeview node_AfterCheck event like this:

```
Private Sub node_AfterCheck(sender As Object, e As TreeViewEventArgs)     Handles TreeView1.AfterCheck

   If e.Action <> TreeViewAction.Unknown Then
      Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub()
                                  GetPolygons(e.Node)
                              End Sub, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning)
   End If
End Sub



Private Sub GetPolygons(node As TreeNode)
            Dim objectId As String
            Dim _polygon As GMapPolygon
            For Each node1 As TreeNode In node.Nodes
                objectId = node1.Name

                For Each _polygon In polyOverlay.Polygons.AsParallel
                    itemTag = _polygon.Tag.ToString.Split("|")
                    If itemTag (0) = node1.Name Then
                        _polygon.IsVisible = node.Checked
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
            Next
End sub
```

this code takes about 40 seconds to run completely. Is there any way to optimize this code to complete in shorter time?

Comment: Also there's some trouble with the order of `End If` and `Exit For`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one thing that I can see that is expensive codewise is the call of `Split` on the tags of the polygon. But this would be subject to measure.

To circumvent the `Split` you could e.g. try to use:

```
If _polygon.Tag.StartsWith(node1.Name) Then
```

Consider [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717855/why-is-function-isprefix-faster-than-startswith-in-c) to find out if `IsPrefix` is even faster in your case.

I'm assuming, however, the main trouble is the constant refresh/redraw of the map ("auto refresh") while setting each polygon's visibility. One thing I found in the sources is to set `Invalidation` on hold:

```
// docs: stops immediate markers/route/polygon invalidations; call Refresh to perform single refresh and reset incalidation state
gmap2.HoldInvalidation = true;

// do your update loop within here

// docs: call this to stop HoldInvalidation and perform single forced instant refresh
gmap2.Refresh();
```

Don't have the the opportunity to give it a try right now, but I guess you can go ahead and try and see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your quick response I changed my code like this:

```
Private Sub GetPolygons(node As TreeNode)

        myMap.HoldInvalidation = True

        Dim objectId As String
        Dim _polygon As GMapPolygon
        For Each node1 As TreeNode In node.Nodes
            objectId = node1.Name

            For Each _polygon In polyOverlay.Polygons.AsParallel
                itemTag = _polygon.Tag.ToString.Split("|")
                If itemTag (0) = node1.Name Then
                    _polygon.IsVisible = node.Checked
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        Next

        myMap.Refresh()
```

End sub

but code is taking more period of time to complete than before.

Comment: by replacing  "_polygon.Tag.ToString.Split("|")" with "_polygon.Tag.StartsWith(node1.Name)" now code takes about 20 seconds rather than 40 seconds.

Comment: Ok, it was worth a try. 17000 polygons are quite a bit, glad to see that removal of the `Split` operation helped, still probably even better w/o any operation on each string, think that's possible? How much time does that operation actually take? Find out by leaving out the visibility setting at all for a try to narrow down where the bottle neck is located. Let's see where we get from there, I want to know.

Comment: Without operation on each string it takes about 2 seconds to complete!

Comment: Good news, time to refactor that `string` op out of the loop. Now that you're down to actual fractions of seconds that could matter, I'd be interested if `HoldInvalidation` does matter.

Comment: No HoldInvalidation doesn't matter. but good news! I placed polygonId in polygon.name instead polygon.tag now I just check: "If string.CompareOrdinal(_polygon.Name, node1.Name) = 0 Then _polygon.IsVisible = node.Checked Exit For End If" now it takes about 5 seconds to complete. Now if I can remove that If I think it will be more optimized